# for(item in myObject) is not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-10

Please any one tell me what is wrong with the following code

HTML:

```
<div id="res"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myObject = {
    "a" : {
        src : "someimagepath_a.png"
    },
    "b" : {
        src : "someimagepath_b.png"
    },
};
var image_srcArr = [];
var image_src = "";
for(item in myObject)
{
   image_srcArr.push(myObject[item].src);
   // blah blah
}        
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = (image_srcArr.join(" & ") + " images used");
```

Where I get the error:

```
var image_src = "";
for(item in myObject)
{
   image_src = myObject[item].src;
   // blah blah
}
```

This works in Fire fox and other browsers. But in IE10 `myObject[item]` is alway undefined even though i have values in `myObject`?

Comment: You should define what myObject is

Comment: The issue is probably related to where myObject has been initialized. Can you post more code? Is it running under strict mode?

Comment: I already defined and initialized it. I just show the code where i get the error.

Comment: What is `myObject`? What is `item`?

Comment: Here is the sample code http://jsfiddle.net/x8ccF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this `for(var item in myObject)`

```
var myObject = {
    "a" : {
        src : "someimagepath_a.png"
    },
    "b" : {
        src : "someimagepath_b.png"
    },
};
var image_srcArr = [];
var image_src = "";
for(var item in myObject)
{
   image_srcArr.push(myObject[item].src);
   // blah blah
}        
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = (image_srcArr.join(" & ") + " images used");
```

Comment: is this that much simple. wow its solved. thanks for the quick answer